# If matter cannot be transformed into information, why do we say that information about matter is lost when we talk about black hole paradox?

Tags: black-holes, information, matter

In this question it is said that matter cannot be transformed into information: [Can matter be converted to information?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109441/can-matter-be-converted-to-information)

But when we talk about black hole information paradox, we say that matter transforms into information and that that information is lost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole

So, how can these two statements be true at the same time? Is matter itself information or not?

Comment: I think there is confusion about subject and properties assigned to a subject.  Information is a property of matter,and information can be transferred from one kind of matter to another, matter itself is not transferable. Example a tree, and a three dimensional hologram of the tree. Information that characterizes  the tree is there in the tree itself (matter) and some of it on the hologram film( a different matter), but there is no tranformation of tree to hologram on a film.

Comment: So what's the answer to the question i quoted referring to then when saying that matter can't be transformed into information? And you say that the tree in an hologram film would not have all the information of the tree itself because there would be different matter. So, here, do you say that because the holographic film is not made of the same matter of the tree, that information of the matter of the tree (leaves, wood, roots...etc) would not be transferable? @annav

Comment: Say you lose a piece of paper with important information on it.  Then you've lost information even if that piece of paper's matter hasn't been destroyed, right?  This topic gets way more complicated - in fact, it's not even always true that we lose information if matter goes into a black hole, even if we assume cosmic censorship.  But at the level you're asking about, the gist is basically the matter tends to have information tied to it, so losing the matter implies losing the information.  Just like losing your wallet tends to imply losing money.

Comment: The hologram on the film does not have the chemical composition , (information carried by the tree), etc, if you want to go into atoms and quarks. I am trying to show that matter has as property various informations, but information does not have matter, it needs matter in order to be expressed.  A recipe is not the food.